# Sequelize create database schema from model

Tags: sequelize.js, database-schema

Can I use sequelize to create the database schema from the available model? I work on a project that has many migrations missing and no tests. To run tests I need to create a new db (sqlite3) but I cannot initialize its schema using migration (because they are missing). Is it possible to use the models to create the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you just sync sequelize in your application, the models will create the database tables for you

Comment: Is there any way to do this from the cli, or in a synchronous manner? Because I want to do this in Mocha config so whenever any test runs, I'm sure that it runs on an up to date test db. But because `sync` is async I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to use the models to create the schema? ... Because I want to do this in Mocha config so whenever any test runs, I'm sure that it runs on an up to date test db. But because sync is async I have no idea how to do this

Assuming Sequelize CLI was used, Here's a way to ensure you have an updated db in any mocha test:

```
  // Force sync without migrations
  // This can be run at the top of every individual test suite
  before(function () {
    return require('../../models').sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  })
```

The path `'../../models'` points to `models/index.js` which Sequelize CLI creates for you.

Comment: Thanks for a more detailed answer. I've already thought about using the  `before` helper, but I prefer to have a global synchronization whenever mocha runs

Comment: @Uko do add an answer if you figure that method out, I'd love to utilize that as well. I currently do not have a global solution, unfortunately.

Comment: I discovered that you can use the `mocha-prepare` npm module. The docs are quite clear and here is the code that I have in the synchronization file that I require in mocha.opts: `prepare((done) => { db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => done()); });`